# Creating multiple Google App Engine Entities in a for loop

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Am trying to create a method that when called will add a new `Entity`.Am trying to use a `for loop` and an `ArrayList` to do this.
So far this is what i have:

```
public void createUserEntity() {
    ArrayList<Entity> user = new ArrayList<Entity>(); 
}
```

The problem is the `Entity` class is from `com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity` and it requires a `key` argument when creating it.For example `Entity user = new Entity("user"); Am not sure how to add this`key`argument when creating a new`Entity`using ArrayList`.

An Attempt at `ArrayList<Entity> user = new ArrayList<Entity>("user");` is flagged with the error message `Remove argument to match 'ArrayList<Entity>()'`

Comment: What you are doing is right. You don't need to create the array like new ArrayList<Entity>("user").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to attempt `ArrayList<Entity> user = new ArrayList<Entity>("user");` since the constructor argument is not correct.

In fact, the way you constructed it was correct.

First up, are you trying to create one entity or multiple entities. Your method name createUserEntity seems to signify just one entity.

I believe you might have to write your code a bit like this:

```
public void createUserEntity(**//Pass** some parameters here) {

  //Instantiate your new Entity over here
  Entity newItem = new Entity("YourEntityName",KeyValue);
  newItem.setProperty("prop1",prop1value);
  newItem.setProperty("prop2",prop2value);
  ...
  //Persist the Entity

}
```

You can pass the key value in the parameters to this method or retrieve it via some generator Class if that is what you are doing.

I have shown you the code for a single entity, you can extend it further if you want to create multiple entities in a loop.

Comment: Am trying to create a new entity each time the method is called.I am not very conversant with persisting objects but judging by your example, is a new entity created and stored every time a call is made to `createUserEntity()`?

Comment: Yes. Every time you need to create a new Entity, you can invoke the `createUserEntity()` method, pass it the parameters for that Entity and make sure you code the Persistence code inside of the `createUserEntity()` method. Please refer to http://googcloudlabs.appspot.com/codelabexercise1.html for details.